# In-app purchases prices are not updated inside the app

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

We have several in-app purchases (consumable) inside the app. One of them previously had price of $2.49, now we decided to set up to $1.99

I've changed prices inside AppStore connect, made two updates of the application, but the prices are still the same. Thought if I install the app from TestFlight (not from AppStore) the prices are updated.

Also the "Start date" of the app updates to today's date every day
Would you please help me out ? Is there anything I'm missing ?

We're using flutter for mobile development

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the prices were actually updated, we haven't noticed because the new tier prices for our country matched prices that we had before with other tier prices for other country